# Manual install of Elasticsearch plugins

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Because my Elasticsearch server is behind a proxy, I can't directly install plugins using the command under bin.

So I tried uncompressing some of them in the plugins directory, with no luck.

Specifically I tried this https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-knapsack and I can't get it to work.

Any help?

Comment: what specifically went wrong? Just compile and drop the jar + all deps under /plugins/knapsack

Comment: yep, it's a bug in elasticsearch: https://github.com/elastic/puppet-elasticsearch/issues/152

Comment: there's no bug, look at the answers.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Typically uncompressing the plugin file into plugins directory should work as long as file access rights are not messed up. To verify that plugin is installed correctly check that elasticsearch home directory contains directory called `plugins/knapsack` and that this directory contains two files: `commons-compress-1.4.1.jar` and `elasticsearch-knapsack-2.1.2.jar`

You can also download plugin zip file to a temporary location and then install it by specifying path to it using `--url` parameter:

```
bin/plugin --install knapsack --url file:///Full/Path/To/elasticsearch-knapsack-2.1.2.zip
```

See [Plugins documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-plugins.html#installing) for more information.

Comment: actually I was doing it right ,but I was testing the plugin using GET instead of POST

Comment: It looks like the parameters have changed in the more recent releases. Now it's just: bin/plugin install file:///Full/Path/To/elasticsearch-knapsack-2.1.2.zip - Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.2/installation.html

Answer (score 9):

I have used the following to install the plugin behind the firewall:

```
bin/plugin -DproxyHost=myproxy.proxy.com -DproxyPort=80 --install lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to work well with proxies requiring authentication, though :-/

Comment: Worked for me, but I am behind an a proxy that doesn't require auth.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Many times, when using Linux inside a Proxied network, I had to install cNTLM or some other software proxy. Anyway, what worked for me is to download the file with the Plugin (ZIP, TAR.GF, whatever) and then just unzip it on the plugins directory. Check file permissions, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I installed elasticsearch using Homebrew on my Mac and was getting this ERROR: Could not find plugin descriptor 'plugin-descriptor.properties' in plugin zip.
The bin directory is /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/2.0.0_1/bin
I did sudo plugin install license first then sudo plugin install marvel-agent and this solved the problem.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/installing-marvel.html